# Show error on Monaco Editor when closing bracket is missing

Tags: angular, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I am using monaco with Angular 5. Here is my custom language configuartion code

```
const config = {
      surroundingPairs: [
        { open: '{', close: '}' },
        { open: '[', close: ']' },
        { open: '(', close: ')' },
        { open: '<', close: '>' },
        { open: "'", close: "'" },
        { open: '"', close: '"' },
      ],
      autoClosingPairs: [
        { open: '{', close: '}' },
        { open: '[', close: ']' },
        { open: '(', close: ')' },
        { open: "'", close: "'", notIn: ['string', 'comment'] },
        { open: '"', close: '"', notIn: ['string', 'comment'] },
      ],
    };
    monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration(customLanguage, config);
```

It is auto closing the brackets but I want to show syntax error if somehow user forget to close the brackets. Like when user write code

```
function() {
console.log("hello world");
```

Monaco should show the syntax error on above line as '}' is missing.

Comment: When you have set a language for the editor it should automatically highlight syntax errors, at least for Javascript and Typescript.

Comment: yes it automatically highlight the syntax  for javascript but what if we are using custom language? How to validate brackets syntax

Comment: Then you have to implement a full parser for your language and manually add error markup to the editor.